# Problems installing PHP 5.4.11 and MySQL 5.6.10 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, mysql, php, centos, installation

I'm attempting to install **PHP 5.4.11** and **MySQL 5.6.10** onto a **CentOS 6.3** box.

I've successfully installed PHP 5.4.11 via the remi repository for yum. I've also successfully installed MySQL 5.6.10 using the community server rpm's on the [MySQL downloads page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html).

They both work fine independently, but when attempting to install `php-mysql` from the remi repository, a dependency of `mysql-libs` is pulled in which is at version 5.5.30, and going ahead with the install produces an array of errors like the following:

```
file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
```

At this point, I'm out of my depth with regards to getting this working. Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get my PHP installation working with MySQL?

Comment: This is a very long standing incompatibility in the way that MySQL builds their "community" RPM packages. I do not recommend using them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `mysql-libs` package:

```
rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs
```

then install the `MySQL-shared-compat` package by running:

```
rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.10-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
```

and try to install `php-mysql` again.

Comment: I've now installed `MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`, but I'm afraid yum is still listing `mysql-libs` as a dependency, and so it still fails... Running `rpm -qa` reveals `MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64`, but no `mysql-libs`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `mysql-libs` package:

```
yum remove mysql-libs
```

It's removing for dependencies: `cronie cronie-anacron crontabs postfix`

Then install the Compatibility Libraries:

```
rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

and install `cronie cronie-anacron crontabs postfix` !

```
yum install cronie cronie-anacron crontabs postfix
```

This is work for me!

Comment: Uograde mysql-libs work too...
`rpm -Uvh MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it working. I installed the MySQL Native Driver instead and everything works great now. It's just php-mysqlnd instead of php-mysql. Here's some info on mysqlnd (I guess it's pretty new, I know I had no idea what it was before today). http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

-------------------------------Original Message--------------------
I'm having the same problem. I think it has to do with Oracle replacing the libmysqlclient.so files with their own so that mysql-libs is no longer needed. The only problem then is that there are conflicts and dependencies. Here's some more info:

Look under MySQL-shared-compat-VERSION.glibc23.i386.rpm
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-rpm.html

It looks like we might be able to use 5.6.4 as it was the last version not to replace libmysqlclient.so but I haven't tested that yet. Here's a link the 5.6.4 rpms.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Having requirement of exact version is not ideal.  In case for strange reasons it happens to be so then you can try following:

1. Install latest php, mysql, mysql-libs and php-mysql packages etc. using yum
2. Download sources for desired version of PHP and MySQL and install them by source, overwriting existing files created by yum/rpm.

I know this is a bad way, but if it works, then may be it would be worth it.